# Bind control to another property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My boss had downloaded a xaml control that I must use in app. It looks like ok but there is a strange trouble with inner logic - the 
property `CurrentColor` (that I need to use in our app) is defined in `control.xaml.cs` file like :

```
public SolidColorBrush CurrentColor
{
     get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(CurrentColorProperty); }
     set
     {
          SetValue(CurrentColorProperty, value);
          ActiveColor = CurrentColor;
     }
}
```

I am using this control in my dialog (that has its own view model class) and 
I am writing this kind of binding:

```
CurrentColor="{Binding myOwnViewModel.ColorActualValue, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

in `myOwnViewModel.cs` (that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) I have my property

```
public SolidColorBrush ColorActualValue{ // here is some logic}
```

But when I debug an app I have never target MY CurrentColor - I am always go to the `CurrentColor` from `control.xaml.cs`

How could I bind this "third party" control to my property from my `ViewModel`?

Perhaps this is because (control.xaml.cs):

```
  public static DependencyProperty CurrentColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentColor", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(ColorPickerComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Chocolate));
        public static RoutedEvent ActiveColorChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ActiveColorChanged",
            RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ColorPickerComboBox));
```

I have found the question [What's wrong with "DataContext = this" in WPF user controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153787/whats-wrong-with-datacontext-this-in-wpf-user-controls) and removed `DataContext = this;` from constructor of this control - but this still not helped

Comment: Set the datacontext to ur viewmodel and then remove the viewmodel from ur binding declaration

Comment: You're binding to a property myOwnViewModel.ColorActualValue but in your ViewModel it names CurrentColor. Check the output window for binding errors.

Comment: GreenEyedAndy - sorry for this mistake I have corrected  the question

Comment: Can you provide some link to the Control project/site/full code?

Comment: How is your DataContext for `ColorPickerComboBox set, and what is it? The binding of `myOwnViewModel.ColorActualValue` looks weird, as it means you're binding to `ColorPickerComboBox.DataContext.myOwnViewModel.ColorActualValue`, and I suspect the `myOwnViewModel` is either a mistake or not public. Most likely you are trying to bind to `ColorPickerComboBox.DataContext.ColorActualValue`, where the DataContext is `myOwnViewModel`. If that's the case, your binding should just be `{Binding ColorActualValue}`

Answer (score 0):

Should the binding look like this?

```
CurrentColor="{Binding ColorActualValue, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

The `DataContext` of your 'dialog' needs to be the ViewModel class that contains the `ColorActualValue` property

```
public Dialog()
{
    DataContext = new myOwnViewModel();
}
```

Comment: no, I have tried this. Any way thank you for the answer and take a look at my updated question

Comment: I could not pass an instance of myOwnViewModel to Dialog constructor - firstly Dialog is in another project, secondly myOwnViewModel is not static class and has parameters that not present in the project where the Dialog is located. I will try to write a proper code after InitializeComponent in the place where myOwnViewModel is available (to change the control to another one with proper DataContext)but I think that this is a bad practise

Comment: Yes doesn't sound good. See how some sample applications are put together